# Three queries in one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a possibility to combine these 3 queries into on?
I tried some queries but they gave me a wrong solutions. A `INNER JOIN` will not show rows if there's no post_id in the website_posts_photos table.

I need all rows shown and per row the photo_code from website_posts_photos where `post_photo_order = 1 AS image1` AND `post_photo_order = 2 AS image2`.

```
$select_list = $database->prepare("SELECT post_id, post_title FROM website_posts WHERE post_status = '1' AND post_online = '1' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 50");
$select_list->execute();

while ($result = $select_list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $post_id = $result['post_id'];

     $select_img1 = $database->prepare("SELECT photo_code FROM website_posts_photos WHERE post_photo_order = '1' AND post_id = :post_id");
     $select_img1->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id);
     $select_img1->execute();
     $result_img1 = $select_img1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     $select_img2 = $database->prepare("SELECT photo_code FROM website_posts_photos WHERE post_photo_order = '2' AND post_id = :post_id");
     $select_img2->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id);
     $select_img2->execute();
     $result_img2 = $select_img2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the `website_posts` table and the `website_posts_photos` into one query.

Would look like this

```
SELECT w2.photo_code FROM website_posts_photos w2, website_posts w1 WHERE w2.post_photo_order = '1' AND w2.post_id = w1.post_id ORDER BY w1.post_date DESC LIMIT 50
```

You can also combine the third query by adding `OR post_photo_order = '2'`.

```
 SELECT w2.photo_code FROM website_posts_photos w2, website_posts w1 WHERE w2.post_photo_order = '1' OR w2.post_photo_order = '2' AND w2.post_id = w1.post_id ORDER BY w1.post_date DESC LIMIT 50
```

If you want to fetch the results you should also add a `order by` w1.post_id and as second order criteria `w2.post_photo_order` as ASC

Answer (score 0):

Consider `CASE` logic. Run the below single SQL query for PHP fetch:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN post_photo_order = '1'
            THEN photo_code
       END AS image1,
       CASE 
            WHEN post_photo_order = '2'
            THEN photo_code
       END AS image2

FROM website_posts_photos ph
INNER JOIN website_posts p
  ON p.post_id = ph.post_id
  AND p.post_status = '1' 
  AND p.post_online = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The **right JOIN** tells that all posts from **websites_post_photos** should be included.

The `IN`-statement in MySQL tells that you should fetch all posts from the column post_photo_order that contains 1 or 2 (in this case).

```
SELECT photo_code FROM website_posts
RIGHT JOIN website_posts_photos ON website_posts_photos.post_id = 
website_posts.post_id
WHERE post_status = '1' AND post_online = '1' AND 
website_posts_photos.post_photo_order IN(1,2)
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: You cannot use this solution if you want the actual images to have the keywords: image1 and image2 directly from your SQL result.

Comment: Just to observe that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry - it's not often used. I agree. That fact does not make it wrong  to use RIGHT JOIN :-)

Comment: True, but for most of us, it is (or at least appears to be) a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: I dont understand @Strawberry. You could as well have left join and switch placements of the tables but it's basically the same thing anyway.

Comment: Exactly. Hence why nobody bothers with RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: Hm. What makes it it more correct to use LEFT JOIN? Nothing at all. Use LEFT JOIN when it's needed and RIGHT JOIN when it's needed. In this case it seemed more natural to use RIGHT JOIN. But it doesn't matter. This "discussion" won't lead anywhere :-)

Comment: I really don't understand your argument. Because we have LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN is never needed. But honestly, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: You could argue that LEFT JOIN is never needed because RIGHT JOIN exists to ;-)

Comment: Yes. Except that the vast popularity of LEFT JOIN over RIGHT JOIN (presently standing at 33,882 results vs 2,873 results on this very forum - 92% vs 8%, if you prefer) indicates that it's more intuitive. It's certainly a sentiment with which I would concur.